# ajax post на сервер без ssl

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, ssl, https

Возможно ли как-то выполнять ajax запрос на сервер без ssl с сервера с ssl?

Мой скрипт работает прекрасно если открываю его через http:// Но он перестал работать после установки ssl сертификата.

```
jQuery.ajax({
  "url": "http://123.123.123.123/api/check.php",
  "type": "POST",
  "data": 'module=check_firm&code='+code,
  success: function(result)
  {
        jQuery(".code").append(result); 
  },
  error: function(result) { 
      jQuery(".code").append(code);
  }  
});
```

> Mixed Content: The page at '' was loaded over HTTPS, but
>   requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint ''. This content
>   should also be served over HTTPS.

Пробовал добавить

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

Все равно не работает

> POST https://123.123.123.123/api/check.php
>   net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Установить сертификат и на сервер к которому обращаюсь возможности нет :(

Comment: Невозможно, потому что небезопасно.

Comment: и нет никаких других выходов отправить и получить даннык кроме как установка сертификата на том сервере?

Comment: Взять другой сервер с сертификатом, чтобы этот сервер сам отправлял всё на сервер без сертификата, например